# Recursive angularjs directive with tds, must have exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a table with nested generic objects.
I want to make a directive that holds the tr, and then below that row call the directive again with the current objects children.

My main view looks like this:

```
            <table class="table ap-table planning_table noselect" id="planningTableNew">
                <thead>
                  <tr>....</tr>
                </thead>
                <thead ng-repeat-start="item in projectVm.viewModel" style="display:none"></thead>
                <tbody planning-list-data item="item" periodes-displayed="periodesDisplayed"></tbody>
                <thead ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></thead>

            </table>
```

My looks like this directive:

```
(function () {
angular.module('appProjects').directive('planningListData', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            parentId: "@",
            item: "=item",
            periodesDisplayed: "=periodesDisplayed",
        },
        templateUrl: '/App/Planning/Directive/PlanningListDataView.html'
    }
}
]);
```

}());

And my directive template:

```
<tr>
    <td class="no_input text-align-right td-fixed td-fixed-margin">{{item.identRowId}}</td>
    <td class="no_input"><i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp{{item.identName}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="child in item.childWebModel" style="display:none"></tr>
    <tr planning-list-data item="child" periodes-displayed="periodesDisplayed"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></tr>
```

When I try to do like this, I get the error:

> Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'planningListData' must
>   have exactly one root element.

I understand why is is an issue, but i can't seem to figure out how to work around it. 
Every solution i have tried so far messes up the table.

The only work around I have found is calling the directive from the main view every time, but that gives me this structure in the main html view.

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in projectVm.viewModel" style="display:none"></tr>
                        <tr planning-list-data item="item" periodes-displayed="periodesDisplayed"></tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-start="child in item.childWebModel" style="display:none"></tr>
                                <tr planning-list-data item="child" periodes-displayed="periodesDisplayed"></tr>
                                    <tr ng-repeat-start="subChild in child.childWebModel" style="display:none"></tr>
                                        <tr planning-list-data item="subChild" periodes-displayed="periodesDisplayed"></tr>
                                            <tr ng-repeat-start="subSubChild in subChild.childWebModel" style="display:none"></tr>
                                                <tr planning-list-data item="subSubChild" periodes-displayed="periodesDisplayed"></tr>
                                                    <tr ng-repeat-start="subSubSubChild in subSubChild.childWebModel" style="display:none"></tr>
                                                        <tr planning-list-data item="subSubSubChild" periodes-displayed="periodesDisplayed"></tr>
                                                    <tr ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></tr>
                                            <tr ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></tr>
                                    <tr ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></tr>
```

And this is not totally suitable since i don't know how deep the nested objects go.

Is their a way to do this is any way? Or do I have to use an ugly and not that maintainable solution?

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps. A table that draws rows and then draws children as new tables with rows with ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end.

I think in your case you're confused when to use the `<td>` plus the trick here is colspan 999 to ensure an entire row is being used to draw a new table; however, thats not mandatory, you can simply draw the new table in a cell `<td>`

[plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/xFInHhLFmuwqsni1zTtk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Do These Changes to you html:-

```
<table class="table ap-table planning_table noselect" id="planningTableNew">
    <thead>
        <tr>....</tr>
    </thead>
    <thead ng-repeat-start="item in projectVm.viewModel" style="display:none"></thead>
    <tbody>
        <planning-list-data item="item" periodes-displayed="periodesDisplayed"></planning-list-data>
    </tbody>
    <thead ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></thead>
</table>
```

And these changes to directives:-

```
(function () {
 angular.module('appProjects').directive('planningListData', [function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        parentId: "@",
        item: "=item",
        periodesDisplayed: "=periodesDisplayed",
    },
    templateUrl: '/App/Planning/Directive/PlanningListDataView.html'
}]);
```

I am Not Sure But Hope This Works!.